# How can I create a task which drives an output across time without using globals?

Tags: system-verilog

I want to write some tasks in a package, and then import that package in some files that use those tasks.

One of these tasks toggles a reset signal. The task is reset_board and the code is as follows:

```
package tb_pkg;
    task reset_board(output logic rst);
        rst <= 1'b0;
        #1;
        rst <= 1'b1;
        #1;
        rst <= 1'b0;
        #1;
    endtask
endpackage
```

However, if I [understand this correctly](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/task_func1.html), outputs are only assigned at the end of execution, so in this case, the `rst` signal will just get set to 0 at the end of the task's execution, which is obviously not what I want.

If this task were declared locally in the module in which it is used, I could refer to the `rst` signal directly (since it is declared in the module). However, this would not allow me to put the task in a separate package. I could put the task in a file and then `include it in the module, but I'm trying to avoid the nasty complications that come with the way SystemVerilog handles includes (long-story-short, it doesn't work the way C does).

So, is there any way that the task can drive an output with different values across the duration of its execution without it having to refer to a global variable?

Comment: What is a global variable. You can control hierarchically, using testbench.rst.

Comment: The was an incorrect word-choice. I really meant to say that the task would be in the same scope as the signal if it were declared inside the module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick solution is to use a `ref` that passes the task argument by reference instead of an `output` argument that is copied after returning from the task.

task reset_board(ref logic rst);

There are a few drawbacks of doing it this way. You can only pass variables of matching types by reference, so when you call `reset_board(*signal*)`, *signal* cannot be a wire. Another problem is you cannot use an NBA `<=` to assign a variable passed by reference, you must use a blocking assignment `=`. This is because you are allowed to pass automatic variables by reference to a task, but automatic variable are not allowed to be assigned by NBAs. There is no way for the task to check the storage type of the argument passed to it. *(* Note that the IEEE 1800-2023 LRM adds a `ref static` argument that forces a static variable type as an actual argument *)*

Standard methodologies like the UVM recommend using virtual interfaces or abstract classes to create these kinds of connections from the testbench to the DUT. See my [DVCon paper](https://dvcon-proceedings.org/wp-content/uploads/the-missing-link-the-testbench-to-dut-connection.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! Wow, lots of good info there. I was wondering if SV had anything like references but I assumed that was too foreign to the language. Reading your paper now...